# How to get right side of delimiter values from a column in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

I have a column as below:

```
       A
0   Australia
1   New Zealand
2   New Jersey,America
3   Hyderabad,India
```

I want to split it in two columns where there is ',' separator such as:

```
        A                  B
0   Australia             NaN
1   New Zealand           NaN
2   New Jersey,America  America
3   Hyderabad,India      India
```

Any suggestion is welcomed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help.

```
df["Country"] = df.City.str.split(',', expand=True )[1]
```

Comment: Jut I notice, it is not dupe, so reopened :) Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
def splitter(x):
   try: 
      y = x.split(",")[1]
   except:
      y = None
   return y
df["B"] = df["A"].apply(splitter)
```